# 'selectany' attribute is only valid on the initialization of global data with external linkage

Tags: c++, c++builder-10-seattle

When I include `<d3d11.h>` file in Embarcadero RadStudio seattle 10 C++ IDE, compiler gives the following error:

> [bcc64 Error] d3d11.h(9622): 'selectany' attribute is only valid on the initialization of global data with external linkage.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

`d3d11.h` is a Microsoft header for Direct3D.

Microsoft's flavor of [`selectany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tkz6s71.aspx) differs slightly from Embarcadero's flavor of [`selectany`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declspec(selectany)).

In particular, Microsoft's flavor supports default-initialization of global object instances, whereas Embarcadero's does not. Globals must be initialized with data.  `d3d11.h` (being a Microsoft header) is relying on Microsoft's `selectany` behavior.  The variable in question (`D3D11_VIDEO_DEFAULT`) is not being initialized with any data, which is OK in Microsoft's compiler but is not OK in Embarcadero's compiler.

You would have to alter Embarcadero's copy of `d3d11.h` to add an initialization:

```
//extern const DECLSPEC_SELECTANY CD3D11_VIDEO_DEFAULT D3D11_VIDEO_DEFAULT;
extern const DECLSPEC_SELECTANY CD3D11_VIDEO_DEFAULT D3D11_VIDEO_DEFAULT = {};
```

Comment: copied the embarcadero d3d11.h header and corrected as above and used the header as

Comment: copied d3d11.h ,corrected as above and included as "d3d11.h". No more errors.